# Manter estilo enquanto tira link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

estou com dificuldade para manter o estilo de um botão retirando o link_to e mantendo apenas o raw:

```
=link_to(raw("<span class='calsse'></span>"), rota)
```

para:

```
=raw("<span class='calsse'></span>")
```

quando faço isso o botão perde todo o estilo, ficando apenas escrito "botão" na página.

Comment: Já tentou `"<span class='classe'></span>".html_safe`?

Comment: acabei de tentar, não deu certo

Comment: O problema não é apenas o nome da classe escrito errado? (Você escreveu `calsse`).

Comment: Provavelmente o estilo que você quer manter está associado a tag `a` no css. Ex:
`a .classe { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acabou que não pude tirar o link_to, então apenas troquei a rota.